# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, bundler

[Unable to solve the problem of Ruby gems in json 1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cgf4.png)

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: If possible, please copy and paste text as part of the question rather than posting screenshots of text. It makes it easier for others to help if they can immediately see the error and copy/paste relevant sections.

Comment: Your rails is relatively old (3.2) but you are trying to use a recent version of Ruby (2.5). Maybe try using an older ruby version or ``bundle update json`` try to get a newer json gem (2.4.0)

Comment: @stwienert Problem still occurs . Please suggest another solution.